# Email ID registered but cannot log in

Tags: account

I had signed up my email ID for salesforce. Using this email ID I cannot log into saleforce.com. At the first we get an email to verify email ID. I tried to do it but its taking me to Log in paage for ID and password ! I have NOT yet set my password. please help

Answer (score 0):

You don't try with your registered email Id. try your **Username** field value. This field you entered manually at the time of registration.

Its looks like an email

**EX:**  test@test.com

Comment: Yup tried it. It was my email ID.

Comment: Ok fine. you try to forgot password link and Enter your username. you will got a salesforce reset password link via email. then you will reset your password and try again..

Comment: I tried the forgot password option as Robin suggested. But we have security questions to answer which are for valid for accounts already set up but not true in my case. Here I cannot even verify the email ID with that link!

Comment: Refer this link https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005251&language=en_US